# html is not updated after adding a class with obj.addCls('foo')

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am developing a webapp with sencha touch 2.2.0 alpha. I am using a navigation view where i push other views. Some elements of these views have to have a different look when the device is offline. To accomplish this I check for navigator.onLine and - if false - I add the class "offline" to the element.
This works as expected the first time I do it on the element. But when I pop the view by pressing the back button and then push the view on the stack again, the class is not added to the html.
As the code shows, I look for all the li-elements in the dom and if their id start with "link" the class is added.
When I log the element I can see the class is not added, but when I log the object ("obj" in the code) the "dom"-property tells me it is. Any ideas what I am doing wrong or misunderstand?

```
if ( !navigator.onLine )
{
    lis = Ext.DomQuery.select('li');

    for ( i = 0; i < lis.length; i ++ )
    {
        if ( lis[i].id.substring(0, 4) == 'link' )
        {   
            obj = Ext.get(lis[i].id);   
            obj.addCls('offline');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can you not just add an offline className to the body, and use that?

Comment: @rdougan is right, just add an offline class to the body, and use the CSS cascade to change the list styles.

Comment: @rdougan Great. Thanks. I still don't understand why my solution does not work, but your answer led me to a solution that fits my problem even better. Indeed it works to set a class to the body-tag dynamically and on every change the html is updated. So now I use a timer to check if the user is online and can add and remove the class as needed. Perfect.

Comment: @Lem I replied to the question which should answer everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above, you should just add a className to the `<body>` and use that in your CSS selectors.

As for your code: it does not work because the DOM structure in Sencha Touch is generated automatically, so when you add a class manually using Ext.DomQuery, it may not stay on the element as it may get deleted/created again. To add a class onto a view/component in Sencha Touch, you should use the `cls` configuration of the view:

```
{
    xtype: 'container',
    html: 'My view!',
    cls: 'myCustomClass'
}
```